# PyPDF2 seems to close file too early

Tags: python, pypdf

i would like to create a .pdf document with python and then rotate it. After some searching, i tried to create the pdf with reportLab. This works fine. But when i´m trying to rotate it with pyPDF2 I always get an error:

ValueError: seek of closed file

This is my Code:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
import PyPDF2

def create_pdf(filename):
    """
    This function creates a PDF file with a single page that contains the text "Hello World" centered on the page.
    """
    c = canvas.Canvas(filename)
    width, height = 210*mm, 205*mm
    text = "Hello World"
    text_width = c.stringWidth(text)
    x = (width - text_width) / 2
    y = height / 2
    c.drawString(x, y, text)
    c.save()

# Call the function to create a PDF file with the text "Hello World" centered on the page
create_pdf('hello_world.pdf')

with open('hello_world.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
    writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

for page in range(len(reader.pages)):
    page = reader.getPage(i)
    page.rotateClockwise(90)  # um 90 Grad im Uhrzeigersinn drehen
    writer.addPage(page)

with open('hello_world_new.pdf', 'wb') as file:
    writer.write(file)
```

It seems like there is a problem with the loop, especially with the len(reader.pages), but in the PyPDF2 Documentation this is the correct form for the former reader.getNumPages() class. I would be happy, if you cold help me.

I change the code form for i in range(reader.getNumPages()): to the new one, i also skipt the Code after the opening of the file. That worked. The problem begins at the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is only open as long as you are in the `with open('hello_world.pdf', 'rb') as file:` block. `PdfReader` also accepts a filename so I would just pass the filename string directly to `PdfReader`.

```py
reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader('hello_world.pdf')
```

Comment: Right.  The `with` statement is fine when you need to limit the file use, but if you need the file to be open through the entire program, as in this case, then forget about `with`.  Just do `file = open(...)`, or use the advice in this answer.